# PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze18

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mysql, php

My provider made a small upgrade on the server and now `phpinfo();` gives me this:

```
PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze18
```

**What does the `+squeeze18` mean?** I google it, but all I got is that it has something to do with mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means it's been [packaged by a Debian maintainer f](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/php5)or inclusion in the Squeeze (6.0) release.